# How to assign roles with a Discord bot made in Java?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm trying to get my Meeseeks bot to assign and remove roles on discord for my personal server. I'm not all too familiar with the special methods and commands, and I've had no luck looking for it!

This is my code right now;

```
package discord.meeseeksBot;

import discord.meeseeksBot.Ref2;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.AccountType;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Message;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.MessageChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.User;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class App extends ListenerAdapter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        JDA jda = new 
        JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).setToken(Ref2.token).buildBlocking();

        jda.addEventListener(new App());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent evt)
    {
        User objUser = evt.getAuthor();
        MessageChannel objMsgCh = evt.getChannel();
        Message objMsg = evt.getMessage();


        //the prefix to which the bot responds to is "Mr.Meeseeks, "
        if(objMsg.getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase(Ref2.prefix+"I need 
help"))
        {
            objMsgCh.sendMessage("Hi, " + objUser.getAsMention() + ", " +  " 
I'm Mr.Meeseeks! Look at me! How can I help?").queue();

            objMsgCh.sendMessage("You can tell me to **ADD** you to a role, 
or **REMOVE** you from a role!").queue();

        }

    }
}
```

I'm working to get the bot to where he'll reply to "Mr.Meeseeks, I need help"
with a list of title roles (these roles serve no hierarchical purpose, nor do they appear separately from online members!) you can choose from, and apply to yourself. I'd also like him to be able to remove yourself from a role.

And example for what I had in mind was a role for gender pronouns, (i.e. "she/her" or "he/him") so that when a profile is clicked on in the server, you'd be able to see what they'd be called.

So you could say, "Mr.Meeseeks, add me to "she/her" pronouns!" and he'd do that for you, or "Mr.Meeseeks, remove me from "she/her" pronouns!".

I can't seem to figure it out for Java.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not too familiar with JDA, as Discord4J is better, but I can point you in the right direction.

You want to use regex to test for "Mr", "Meeseeks", "add", and "me" all in the same message. Then you can test for the gender pronouns:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent evt) {
    User objUser = evt.getAuthor();
    MessageChannel objMsgCh = evt.getChannel();
    Message objMsg = evt.getMessage();
    String content = objMsg.getContentRaw();
    Guild guild = evt.getGuild();

    //the prefix to which the bot responds to is "Mr.Meeseeks, "
    if (objMsg.getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase(Ref2.prefix + "I need help")) {
        objMsgCh.sendMessage("Hi, " + objUser.getAsMention() + ", " + " I'm Mr.Meeseeks! Look at me! How can I help?").queue();

        objMsgCh.sendMessage("You can tell me to **ADD** you to a role, or **REMOVE** you from a role!").queue();

    // Test for "Mr", "Meeseeks", "add", and "me".
    } else if (content.matches("^(?=.*\\badd\\b)(?=.*\\bme\\b)(?=.*\\bto\\b)(?=.*\\bMr\\b)(?=.*\\bMeeseeks\\b).+")) {
        // Test for pronouns (Assuming your roles names are "he/him" and "she/her")
        Role group = content.matches("((she)|(her))") ? guild.getRolesByName("she/her", true).get(0) :
            content.matches("((he)|(him))") ? guild.getRolesByName("he/him", true).get(0) : null;
        if (group == null) {
            // Let the user know if they used an invalid pronoun.
            objMsgCh.sendMessage("Sorry " + objUser.getAsMention() + ", I can't find that role!").queue();
        } else {
            // Assign the role.
            guild.getController().addRolesToMember​(guild.getMember(objUser), group);
            objMsgCh.sendMessage("Added " + objUser.getAsMention() + " to " + group.getName() + "!").queue();
        }
    }
}
```